# Grid Layout inside tabs

Tags: polymer

I have polymer element that uses a grid layout and I'm not trying to stick that into a tab, or more precisely as a child of a `polymer-ui-pages` element that I use as the contents for a `ui-polymer-tabs` element

I've built an example where I was trying to get this to work. The full source is at http://jsbin.com/mohem/40/edit

Here are some excerpts.

**A test grid**

```
<polymer-element name="my-grid">
<template>

  <polymer-grid-layout id="gridLayout"  layout="{{layout}}"></polymer-grid-layout>          
  <heading>Heading One</heading>
  <panel flex></panel>
  <main>Main Content</main>

</template>

<script>

  Polymer('my-grid', {
    ready: function() {
     this.layout=[[1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]];
    }
  })

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

which can be displayed with

```
<my-grid></my-grid>
```

and displays as expected

Now I try to put that in tabs

```
<polymer-element name="tabs-with-grid" attributes="selectedTab">
<template>

<polymer-ui-tabs selected="{{selectedTab}}">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
</polymer-ui-tabs>

<polymer-ui-pages selected="{{selectedTab}}">
  <my-grid ></my-grid>
  <div>Page Two</div>
</polymer-ui-pages>

</template>

<script>

  Polymer('tabs-with-grid', {
    ready: function() {
      this.selectedTab = 0;
    }
  });

</script>
</polymer-element>
```

And display with

```
<tabs-with-grid></tabs-with-grid>
```

Which does not display at all like I was expecting. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit

I've made some progress. Firstly I had failed to lay out the tabs relative to the pages. So I put them in a vertical polymer-layout

The next issue is that the children of the polymer-ui-pages have 0 size. So I manually set the size on a div that contains the grid.

http://jsbin.com/vaxev/1/edit

What I really wanted though was the polymer-ui-pages to take up all the space that it's parent polymer-layout gives it.

I'm trying to create a UI that takes up the full size of the browser page without any scroll bars etc. i.e. as the browser window size is changed the layout adapts to keep the ui fully displayed. Although being able to control minimum sizes would be great too.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really needed to do here was style the `<tabs-with-grid>` so that it has a size. Since you want it to fit the window, one easy way to do this is with another `<polymer-layout>` (but you could also do it with straight CSS).

Here is a version that I believe is what you wanted from your first pass. Note there are no hard-coded sizes anywhere:

http://jsbin.com/meliz/1/edit

> Although being able to control minimum sizes would be great too. Is this possible?

Yup, here I simply added `min-width: 1024px` style to `<tabs-with-grid>`:

http://jsbin.com/bijol/1/edit

Btw, good job figuring out `grid`. =P

Comment: Great thanks a lot for your help again. Clearly my crap css skills are showing.
Actually now that I semi figured out grid I think I'm about to abandon it in favour of polymer-layouts. That is more like I used to work in the old school Java Swing days.
And jsbin is very useful. I've switched to building up a UI strawman there then porting it to dart. Would love to have a dartbin.com.
When you suck at css like I do it's much easier to build it up piece by piece interactively rather than debugging a big ui later

Comment: Fwiw, the reason `polymer-grid` exists is to give you a single container with a 2-d layout. With CSS transitions, when you alter the grid settings, your UI can _morph_ between states (i.e. panels can animate in/out, or from one position to another). `polymer-layout` (and `polymer-flex-layout`) only work in one dimension (which is completely fine if you don't need the animations). Re: 'build it up piece by piece', this is something Polymer/web-components wants to encourage: by breaking your application into custom elements, you can use composition to divide-and-conquer the complexity.